# XPath queries in Google Chrome console

Tags: google-chrome, xpath

I can use XPath queries in Google Chrome's console like that:

```
a = $x('my/path')
```

However, what if I want to find an XPath relatively to another object? E.g.:

```
b = a.$x('my/path')
```

(does not work), also:

```
b = $x('my/path', a)
```

fails with: `NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The context node provided is null.`

Does anybody know how to evaluate relative XPaths in Google Chrome's developer console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Evaluating `$x` returns ...

```
function $x(xpath, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

So, the syntax is `$x('my/path', a)`.

Important is that, `$x` returns an array but `startNode`requires a DOM node, so you have to take an *element* of the first query. The following sample demonstrates the behavior on the current page.

```
a = $x("//*[@id='question-header']")
> [ <div id=​"question-header">​…​</div>​ ]

b = $x(".//*[@href]/text()", a[0])
> [ "XPath queries in Google Chrome console" ]
```

**Update:** Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#xpath).